# Highcharts how to use a percentage area with time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For a project of mine i need to use a percentage area (Highcharts js) to display data by day but I don't managed to transform the example given by Highcharts.

Basically, I want this (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked-percent) with a 24 hours range on the x Axis.

Would someone have an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYraZ/) summarized below

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type:'area'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
            },

                area: {
                    stacking: 'percent',
                    lineColor: '#ffffff',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        lineColor: '#ffffff'
                    }
                }
            },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1,     95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5,     106.4, 129.2]
        }]
    });
});
```

EDIT : I you want to be more specific for the days, construct your series data as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VYraZ/3/)

```
data: [{x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),y:29.9},  {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),y:71.5},    
       {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3),y:106.4}, {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4),y:129.2}, 
       {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0,5),y:144.0},  {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6),y:176.0}, 
       {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7),y:135.6}, {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8),y:148.5}, 
       {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 9),y:216.4}, {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 10),y:194.1}, 
       {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 11),y:95.6}, {x:Date.UTC(2010, 0, 12),y:54.4}
]
```

Be careful as to have datas for each day in both series (even 0), or you'll drive the renderer mad...

Comment: Thanks it helped me! But do you know how I could add the dates value directly ? So I will add the dates for X + the values  the percentage (Y).

Comment: Just put points in your series. I've edited the code accordingly